# Intellij is not showing output for simple code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("first int is "+ a + " second int is "+b);
    }
}
```

and this is how i printed arguments:
[image: print arguments]

I’m new to java and also this software..

Comment: you are running an incorrect command to run your code. You are also using an invalid way to provide the input to your code

Comment: @Abra yes..I gave a link on how I input my arguments..please check

Comment: Remove the first three lines in method `main` and replace the last line with this. `System.out.println("first int is " + args[0] + " second int is " + args[1]);`

Comment: @Abra Thank you..it worked..but I still dont understand..what is the use of scanner then ?..also how to write if my arguments are big sentences with spaces in between them..like args[0] = hello world args[1] = this is bot..what should i do then

Comment: @shyantanvullingala you are not using the scanner class, so what's the use? If you want to read an entire line, don't use the command line arguments, but use the Scanner class, and use nextLine(), but learn how to use it first

Answer (score 2):

You need to run Main class to get output. Right click on class which is having your main method and click on run you will get output in console

Comment: I did the same..""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=56333:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -classpath C:\Users\shyanthan\IdeaProjects\test\out\production\test Main 100 200"..it is showing this